# Why does jquery tmpl not parse my {{ if }}?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a jquery template containing an if but it won't evaluate the if - it just outputs the value as-is. I have found several examples and documentation showing that this should work.

What am i doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/G4J5u/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra space in the template tags:

Yours:

```
{{ if disabled}}disabled{{ /if }}
```

Correct:

```
{{if disabled}}disabled{{/if}}
```

Tested it on JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks :) Was driving me crazy - unfortunately i need to wait 5min to accept the answer, but i'll get around ;)